# ASP.NET MVC3 database creation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

So, I am in class and we create the database the good ol fashioned way by logging into the database via a host and running sql commands to create table blah blah blah. This is the way I am used to coming from the php side of things with simple web sites.

Then I ran into the tutorials (http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/adding-a-model) that use DBContext to generate the db structure via I believe scaffolding. Is this a new feature that we are expected to use as part of that framework? Or is it not a best practice to use this feature. Security vs. Functionality what are the pros/cons of each if any. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Well, how do you like the idea of not having to ever really care if you have a database? Do you like writing a data access layer or would you rather create your class and let the MVC framework worry about how to persist it?

I think there are pros and cons to each approach. Some of the auto-generated database stuff can be a little kludgy and I personally enjoy creating databases anyway.

Here's an article that might help:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg685489.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I do like the idea of automation but I've heard negative regarding scaffolding in other languages but that has been for basic CRUD and not for application development. Sorry I am fairly new to the MVC side of programming. Thanks for the read again!